# Moderator Pro Tempore Nominations

Tags: discussion, moderation

We're about 8 days into Public Beta, so let's start seeing nominations for becoming a  moderator.

According to the blog post [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) and following [the 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/), let's see how is a moderator appointed and other important info.

If you nominate someone else, you could write why you are nominating that user.

Vote up who you think is an appropriate candidate, and down who you think is not a good fit. Votes on nominations indicate a rough acceptance by the community.

The Pro Tempore moderators are *appointed* by the Team. When the site will graduate, it will hold its own [Site election](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/).

---

- **Each nomination should be a separate answer**. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
- **Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged**. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.”
- Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

### How Moderators are Appointed Pro Tem

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Answer (score 7):

[Armen Tsirunyan](https://russian.stackexchange.com/users/104/armen-tsirunyan), [meta](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/users/104/armen-tsirunyan)

- He's one of the highest rep users at the moment.
- Third for number of edits and first for number of votes cast. He also participated in Meta (also answering a question about the FAQ points).
- He is over 35K in SO, so he does have basic experience about how the SE sites work.

Comment: @Armen, add a paragraph below what I wrote, writing about yourself and if you accept the nomination.

Answer (score 6):

[Quassnoi](https://russian.stackexchange.com/users/134/quassnoi) ([meta](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/users/134/quassnoi))

- He's *very* active: (currently) 46 answers with consistently positive upvote scores, most of them accepted as best answers.
- very experienced on StackExchange: over 100k rep on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55159/quassnoi) and active on a variety of other StackExchange sites, especially on [Meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/132020/quassnoi).
- Russian.

*Quassnoi*: thanks for nominating, let's try it.

Answer (score 4):

[Olga](https://russian.stackexchange.com/users/185/olga), [meta](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/users/185/olga)

I want to use self-nomination as a way to say that I'm interested in being a moderator.

- I am actively participating in asking, answering and reviewing questions and I am trying to organize the site content so that it is easy to search.
- As much as I like the site, I've advertised it on Facebook. I was glad to see that [one of my friends](https://russian.stackexchange.com/users/224/alex-om) showed up.
- I consider myself a polite and tactful person who thinks things through before acting.
- I've registered on Stack Exchange only recently and will be happy to learn from someone more experienced in site moderation.

Answer (score 3):

[Alenanno](https://russian.stackexchange.com/users/71/alenanno), [meta](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/users/71/alenanno)

> I'm proposing myself as a **reserve** in case there is a sudden need of moderation in the future or if there aren't enough candidates. If everything goes well, consider myself **after** the existing nominations. Thank you. :)

- My reputation is not the highest but I'm  already a Pro Tempore Moderator on the [Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) and the [Chinese SE](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/). For this reason, I think I could help with my experience and use it to appropriately moderate the site.
- I'm always editing and proposing edits and commenting questions that need reviewing or some fixes.
- I'm also really easy-going and available for any type of (constructive) discussion. I try to be impartial in my decisions and in case I'm in doubt, I ask my fellow mods, both from my site or in other sites.

If I'm not appointed, I'll be available for the mods for any advice, so feel free to ping me on chat. :) For any additional info, comment my answer and I'll edit it to answer your questions.

Comment: By the way, you can use my answer as an example for your nomination.